# How do I prevent Structuremap nested container from disposing an instance

Tags: structuremap

I'm using a "nested container per request" pattern.  It's wrapped in a using block so the nested container is disposed after handling the request.  This causes all instances created by the nested container to also be disposed at the end of the request.

This works great and is usually exactly what I want to happen.  However I have ran into a use case where I don't want one particular instance to be disposed while everything else is.

I tried explicitly removing the instance at the bottom of the using block like so:

```
using (var nestedContainer = _container.GetNestedContainer())
{
    nestedContainer.Configure ( x => 
        x.For<IFoo>()
        .Use(getFooForRequest())
    );

    var handler = (IRequestHandler) nestedContainer.GetInstance(handlerType);

    handler.execute(....)

    nestedContainer.EjectAllInstancesOf<IFoo>();
}
```

Unfortunately it appears that EjectAllInstancesOf is also calling dispose.

My application has a few different instances of IFoo, and they all need to live for the entire lifetime of the application.  However incoming requests need to be dynamically associated with one particular instance of IFoo.

Injecting it into the nested container like above accomplished this goal, but my IFoo is getting disposed with the nested container, which is bad.

So how do I block the dispose for IFoo while still letting it dispose everything else?

If that's not possible, is there some other way to dynamically select my per-request IFoo without manual injection via nested.Configure()?

Comment: Can't you use named instances and fetch the correct instance using a determined name per request?

Comment: That is an interesting idea.  I'll give it a try.